# How to connect the Signal an the Slot in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, qt4, signals-slots

My compile environment is PyQt4,Qt4,Python2.In my code,there is a Signal:

```
class ReadThread(QtCore.QThread):
    #always read UART RX pin
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self,parent)
        self.trigger=QtCore.pyqtSignal()#creat a signal

    def run(self):
        #thread stop when the "run" function is over
        for i in range (25536):
            pass
        self.trigger.emit()
```

And there is a Slot() in Class ChatDialog.

```
class ChatDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    #dialog contain two widget-"recived"and"send"
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui=Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def print_slot():
        print "reciece str"
```

I write the __main__like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        myqq=ChatDialog()
        myqq.show()
        read=ReadThread()
        read.trigger.connect(myqq.print_slot,QueuedConnection)
        read.start()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But my "read.trigger.connect(myqq.print_slot,QueuedConnection)" is wrong.How can I connect the Signal and the Slot?Thanks

Comment: Define it on the class, not the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signals have to be defined as a class attributes.  You cannot create signals on instances.

```
class ReadThread(QtCore.QThread):

    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self,parent)
```

Comment: Thanks!My Signal is wrong but how the "connect" could write.

Comment: I modify the "connect" to be <pre><code>read.trigger.connect(myqq.print_slot,Qtcore.Qt.QueuedConnection)</pre></code>and the code can run.But there is a wrong:"pint_slot() takes no arguments (1given)

Comment: Oh,this should be "def print_slot(self):",I forget a "self".